# A thread call a function multiple time

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Say there is this integer `A`. Each time `func()` runs, increases `A` by 1. And I call this function with 2 threads. Example: If the user give an input 5, each thread run 5 times, which makes `A = 10`.

This is what I have in Main Thread:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)   
{ 
   pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, (void*)func, (void*)args);
   pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, (void*)func, (void*)args2);
}
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
```

My way is that, if the user wants each thread runs 5 times. I will make a loop and each time it create "new" thread, which is actually overwritting. I think we can say that I called 10 threads or I used `pthread_create()` 10 times.

But I was told that this is wrong. It should be that I created 2 threads only, and each thread run 5 times. But then I don't understand, how can I call the function 5 times with each thread. I must use `pthread_create()` each time if I want to threading a function, right?

Is there anyway that without looping `pthread_create()` 5 times, I can still call `func()` 5 times with threading?

Comment: You can't run one thread 5 times, what you can do is to run 5 threads executing the same function. I think you have some problems with terminology.

Comment: Once a thread is terminated it cannot be run again.

Comment: Note that if you have more than one thread accessing the variable `A`, you need to control access to it (e.g. with a mutex) to ensure that you don't get weird results.  With addition, you might never spot the problem, but in general, it is bad to have multiple threads accessing the same variable at the same time, whether for read or write.

Comment: Your code only waits for the last 2 of the 10 threads.  That's not a good idea.

Comment: Imagine that you wrote a function named, say, `func_loop` that called `func` some number of times, where the number of times was specified by an parameter to `func_loop`.  Now imagine that your main program started a thread that executed your `func_loop` function with an argument value that was read from a global variable defined by your program.  Imagine that that value was `5`. And then imagine that your main program started another thread that does exactly what the first thread does. If you had those things, you'd be on your way to a solution.

Comment: Good question. If a specific thread can run the same function over and over again, we could get away with (for example) having two threads run the same function five times each, rather than creating ten threads that run the function one time each. The obvious gain would be less overhead. - I take it that the cost in overhead is much smaller for creating _two_ threads than for creating _ten_ threads. I think it should be possible to create 2 threads only, and have each thread run 5 times. The question is how? (The solution might be to use barriers, I think.)

Comment: It is true I think, as Achal writes, that you can never run _the same_ thread more than once. But that is not what you are asking, as I understand your question. Reference: https://riptutorial.com/multithreading/example/31802/can-the-same-thread-run-twice-.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way you can run `one run thread` more than one time because `for n number of thread creation, you have to declare that many no of threads` and threads shares the address space of the process in which they are running and have their own stack to run the thread function once return status is collected using `pthread_join()`, `thread_1` is completed, can't run again. `thread1`.

So only solution is either create 5 `pthread_t` variable or create `array of pthread_t`.

**Solution-1** :

```
 int main()
    {
        pthread_t thread1,thread2,thread3,thread4,thread5;
        pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, (void*)func1, (void*)args1);
        pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, (void*)func2, (void*)args2);
        pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, (void*)func3, (void*)args3);
        pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, (void*)func4, (void*)args4);
        pthread_create(&thread5, NULL, (void*)func5, (void*)args5);

        //and that many times you should use pthread_join() to avoid undefined behaviour
        /*If multiple threads simultaneously try to join with the same thread, the results are undefined. If the thread calling pthread_join() is cancelled,
then the target thread will remain joinable*/

        pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
        ...
        pthread_join(thread5, NULL);
 }
```

**Solution 2** :

```
pthread_t thread_var[5];
for(i=0 ;i<5 ;i++) {
pthread_create(&thread_var[i],NULL,/** call through fun-ptr**/,(void*)args);
}
```

As pointed by others  Since you defined only one handler `func` for 5 thread, all threads are accessing `same thread handler(func)`, it may yields in `unexpected result` as all threads try to `access/modify` same variables inside `func`.

**Is there anyway that without looping pthread_create() 5 times, I can still call func() 5 times with threading?**

I think intention may be that not to call `func() from main thread` 5 times that's not possible instead run `main thread only once` and from `func()` you can do switching between different `thread_handler` using `mutex`.

```
pthread_mutex_t m1,m2,m3;
void* fun1(void *p)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
    /** do ssome task here**/
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);
}
void* fun2(void *p)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m2);
    /** do some task here **/
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m3);
}
void* fun3(void *p)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m3);
    /*** do some task here **/
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
}
```